# Why this connected planar graph doesn't meet the Euler's formula?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

I have a rotation system and try to draw the planar graph. However, after I do a facial walk of the rotation system, and the number of vertices, number of edges, and number of faces don't meet the Euler's formula. Where are my mistakes?

Here are some [slides](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i_tATTSQ9IO_VlOggZAUI3fzouvz_bN5/view?usp=sharing) talking about the facial walk on rotation system(page 10 to 11)

The following is the rotation system (clockwise)

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    a: & b & d & g \\
    b: & d & c & a \\
    c: & b & e & d \\
    d: & a & c & b \\
    e: & h & c & f \\
    f: & h & g & e \\
    g: & a & h & f \\
    h: & f & e & g \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

The following are the facial walk (4 faces)

$F_0 = (a, b)(b, d)(d, a)(a, g)(g, h)(h, f)(f, g)(g, a)(a, b)$

$F_1 = (a, d)(d, c)(c, d)(b, a)(a, d)$

$F_2 = (b, c)(c, e)(e, f)(f, h)(h, e)(e, c)(c, d)(d, b)(b, c)$

$F_3 = (e, h)(h, g)(g, f)(f, e)(e, h)$

The following the planar graph I produced based on the rotation system
[image: Graph]
However, there are 8 vertices, 12 edges, 4 faces, which don't meet the Euler's formula ($n - m + f = 2$).

Anything suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The face count includes the face outside the figure.

Comment: There are $6$ faces, not $4$.  There are $5$ bounded faces and one unbounded one.

Comment: @saulspatz I thought the facial walk will produce all the faces...

Comment: @Andy I don't think I know what the facial walk is.  You can see there are five bounded faces: four triangles and a quadrilateral, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

For the graph that you have drawn, I count $\color{blue}{ 8 \text{ vertices}}$ (numbered in blue), $\color{green}{ 12 \text{ edges}}$ (numbered in green), and $\color{red}{ 6 \text{ faces}}$ (numbered in red; note that one of the faces is the exterior face, i.e. the region outside of the graph).  Euler's formula then gives us
$$ V - E + F
= 8 - 12 + 6
= 2,
$$
which is the expected result.

Note that this graph does *not* correspond to the rotation system that you have written down.  This graph corresponds to the rotation system
$$\begin{matrix}
a: & b & d & g \\
b: & c & d & a & * \\
c: & e & d & b \\
d: & c & a & b & * \\
e: & h & f & c & * \\
f: & e & h & g \\
g: & f & h & a & *\\
h: & g & f & e
\end{matrix}$$
The marked entries are those that differ from what you have written.  I believe that the rotation system you have written down does not correspond to a planar graph.  Indeed, the fact that it has Euler characteristic not equal to 2 indicates this fact.  I would be willing to bet that the rotation system you have written down *could* be embedded in a surface of genus 1, i.e. a torus.  However, I do not have a donut or bagel handy, nor would I want to mark up such a thing with a marker, so I cannot confirm that this would work.

Comment: Thanks for your drawing. But I am confused about the facial walk. I thought do a facial walk on the rotation system will produce all the faces. But it seems the facial walk does not work.

Comment: @Andy You are going to have to define a "facial walk" for me.  Google gives me some... questionable... results.

Comment: Please see the update question. I add some slides talking about the facial work.

Comment: You forgot the line for $d$ when reproducing the table (except its star ended up at $c$),

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ack!  Well, who needs the "d"? Just a sec... and thanks, it is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Some of your "rotation system" entries seem to be in the wrong order. The lines
$$ b : d \; c\; a \\  d : a\; c\; b \\
e : h\; c\; f \\
g : a\; h\; f $$
are not clockwise. This throws your face computation off.

Comment: OK I guess I can re draw the graph to meet the rotation system... But the main question is about why the facial work doesn't produce all the faces. Or I have some misunderstanding about the facial work?

Comment: @Andy: Are you sure you can draw the graph such that all of your lines are clockwise? I don't think you can.